# Sebwite category side bar Link showing error 404

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, sidebar, sidemenu

I installed the Sebwite side-bar category extension successfully for the project,  I'm currently working on and it is showing perfectly on the front end.

I created a separate root category for the sidebar and it's showing perfectly on the front end.

The issue is if I click on any category on the sidebar it shows error 404. I have tried different approaches but all in vain.

I need you guys to help me out on this.
All suggestions and solutions will be highly appreciated

website url: http://34.30.93.236